# Factory pattern vs constructor pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I saw a tutorial about design pattern in javascript. Although tutorial was good it left me with few question.

As I see Factory and constructor produce the same result. So what is the difference between both of them? What are the use case scenarios for each one?

**Factory pattern**

```
function factoryPattern(data) {
  var factory = {};
  factory.name = data.name;
  factory.title = data.title;
  factory.startDate = data.startDate;
  return factory;
}
var factoryUse = factoryPattern(jsonObj);
```

**Constructor pattern**

```
function constructorPattern(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  this.title = data.title;
  this.startDate = data.startDate;
}

var constructorUse = new constructorPattern();
```

**Edit**: As explained by @Michael Warner. Factory method return immutable object which has no link to their creater after they created.

But in constructor patter they do have link with them.

So having a practical use case would be much better to understand why sometimes is good to have object which has link to their constructor.

Comment: The factory pattern can produce old objects from cache, if for example it was creating immutable objects from the input

Comment: @JosephYoung: I am sorry but I did not get you. Can you please explain it as a laymen term

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Factories create an object and returns it. That is about it. The object that is created stands alone and the best part about this is you can use that object and not be effected by what happens to the other objects. This is know as a singleton.

```
var Car = function(){
    var car = {};
    car.running = false;
    car.toggleEngine = function(){
        this.running = !this.running;
    }
    return car;
};

car1 = Car(); // running false
car2 = Car(); // running false
car1.toggleEngine(); // running true
car2.toggleEngine = undefined; // to broke down.
car1.toggleEngine(); //running false
```

Constructors add code to the function so you have a link to the prototype of the object constructor. The nice part about this additional link is to use the functional shared technique which looks like this.

```
var Car = function (){
    this.running = false;
};
Car.prototype.toggleEngine = function(){
    this.running = !this.running;
}
var car1 = new Car; //running false
var car2 = new Car; //running false

car2.toggleEngine() //running true
Car.prototype.toggleEngine = function(){};
car1.toggleEngine() //running false
```

As we can see after the objects were created they still were very much linked together.

To be clear you can still do the following and not effect the objects created by the constructor. With functional shared method and mask the prototype function given by the constructor. So there are not fully linked but they are linked through the constructors prototype.

```
var car1 = new Car; //running false
var car2 = new Car; //running false

car2.toggleEngine() //running true
car2.toggleEngine = function(){};
car1.toggleEngine() //running true
```

Comment: ok, that was nice explanation, So can you point me use case where having a link to constructor function is useful

Comment: Using constructor functions are best practice for memory management as the system only declares one set of functions that are attached to the prototype. It also sets you up to create es2015 classes. They are the same thing just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

With a factory, you have complete freedom on the object to return, so you can choose one constructor or another based on your input data, or the time of the day, or even not constructing anything at all - when using a factory to return sigletons.

On the contrary a constructor basically instantiates an object with a specific prototype, which you can configure afterwards, in the body of the constructor function.